# How to access return value of a callback function present inside a Future method | Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

**auth.dart**

```
class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // Sign in with Phone Number Future<bool>
  Future signInWithPhone(String phone, BuildContext context) async {

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (AuthCredential credential) async {
      ..
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (AuthException exception) {
      // This is the return value which i want to access outside of this callback
      return exception.message;
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent = (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
        ...
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout = (String verificationId) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        ...
    };

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phone,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,        
      codeSent: codeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout
    );

    // Trying to access the callback value
    print(verificationFailed);
 }
}
```

**login.dart**

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

     // here i am calling the phonesign in method
      await _auth.signInWithPhone(phoneNumber, context);

     // and here i want to show the message

    );
  }

}
```

**What is the Problem?**

The problem is i want to access the value of any callback of the **verifyPhoneNumber** , For example **verificationFailed** which returns an exception message and i want to access it outside so that i can use that in other widgets.

**What i have tried so far?**

1) I have tried printing it and it returns **AuthException Closure: () => String** I Don't know how to access the value.

2) I have tried using **setState** but as my class is not inside a **statefulWidget** i can't assign that value to a variable

***Why i need it? ***

Look i have two pages one is called `login.dart` and 2nd is called `auth.dart` .In my auth page i mostly place the classes and code thats related to backend (to properly organize the code) and in the login page i have a stateful widget, consising of a phone textfield and on submit i call the method ***signInWithPhone*** .Everything works but if any error appears such as wrong user phone number format then the ***verificationFailed*** callback is triggered and thus i want to access the return value outside(bcz we cant directly get the return value) so that i can show it from where i called it.

Can anybody please help me so that i can continue my code.

Comment: Please, explain why you need to access the callback so we can help. You might be trying to approach an issue in a difficult way.

Comment: Look i have two pages one is called `login.dart` and 2nd is called `auth.dart` .In my auth page i mostly place the classes and code thats related to backend (to properly organize the code) and in the login page i have a stateful widget, consising of a phone textfield and on submit i call the method ***signInWithPhone*** .Everything works but if any error appears such as wrong user phone number format then the ***verificationFailed*** callback is triggered and thus i want to access the return value outside(bcz we cant directly get the return value) so that i can show it from where i called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear now what you're trying to do. Using Provider is one way to do it. Another way is to pass a callback to Login Page:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final Function(String) verificationMessage;

      const LoginPage({Key key, this.verificationMessage}) : super(key: key);

     @override
     _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
    …
    …
    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (AuthException exception) {

       widget.verificationMessage(exception.message);’
    };
}
```

Now you just pass a callback function whenever you call LoginPage

```
LoginPage(verificationMessage: (String message) => {
    setState(() {
        // Do what you want with the message
    })
})
```

In your case:

auth.dart

```
class AuthService {

  **final Function(String) verificationMessage;**
  **AuthService({@required this.verificationMessage});**

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // Sign in with Phone Number Future<bool>
  Future signInWithPhone(String phone, BuildContext context) async {

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (AuthCredential credential) async {
      ..
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (AuthException exception) {
      // This is the return value which i want to access outside of this callback
       **verificationMessage(exception.message);**
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent = (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
        ...
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout = (String verificationId) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        ...
    };

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phone,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,        
      codeSent: codeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout
    );

    // Trying to access the callback value
    print(verificationFailed);
 }
}
```

login.dart

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  String message = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
         child: Column( 
          children: [
            Text(message),
            Flatbutton(
              .... 
              onPressed: (){
               AuthService(verificationMessage: (String newMessage) => {
                 setState(() {
                   message = newMessage
                 })
               })
              }
            )
          ]
         )
    );
  }



}
```

Comment: where i ll be using the part of code ? `LoginPage(verificationMessage....` ?

Comment: Where ever you want to call LoginPage! this is how you pass the callback parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the response i think this is the correct answer but the problem is i am not able to understand it .I have updated my question above. Can you please put in the code so that i can understand it how it works As on my side i don't know where to place it. I 'll appreciate the effort. :)

Comment: the "message" return nothing i.e an empty string

Comment: I need to see what you've done so I can understand what went wrong. Is the callback working?

Comment: Thanks for the cooperation It indeed works but the message is `Closure: (AuthException) => dynamic`

Comment: Add print(exception.message) and print(exception.code) in verificationFailed, And let me know if it's the same message passed with the callback

Comment: No After directly using `print` its not the same it is the proper error message.

Comment: It could be a type issue. Could you check if hardcoding a string in verificationFailed would show the same string. Replace verificationMessage(exception.message); to verificationMessage("Verification failed"); Hopefully this will help you debug your code.

Comment: Well thanks for that its working now. There were some mistakes in my code .Huge thanks for such support and effort

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make your widget stateful, then you can do this:

```
final PhoneVerificationFailed verifiFailed = (AuthException exception) {
  setState(() {
    errorMessage = exception.message;
  });

  print('${exception.message}');
};
```

It's very easy to switch your widget to be stateful:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return Column(children: [
       ...
       errorMessage == null ? SizedBox() : Text( errorMessage),
       ...
   ]);
  }
}
```

When errorMessage is updated inside the setState the error message will be present.

You can also use Provider; here are a few links for you to look them up:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-firebase-login-using-provider-package-54ee4e5083c7

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjY1_LaXyd8

https://medium.com/@JigneshPatel23/how-to-implement-an-authentication-feature-using-a-provider-in-flutter-1f351447d09d

Comment: aren't there any other approachs? as i have a class AuthService and i need to update it in lots of pages to make the statefulwidget accessible

Comment: plus in your code `print(errorMessage);` should be the correct way to do?

Comment: Yes there's other ways, I just find it easier this way for me.
You can use Provider for example

Comment: ok if i go with the statefulwidget then how can i access the `_LoginPageState` methods through `LoginPage` ?

Comment: or if i go with the Provider way Can you provide an example of Provider? in such scenario?

Comment: I added a few links for using Provider with authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the links ... i am checking them now . In the meantime a basic example related to my scenario might help me ? Can you provide one ?

Comment: i dont want to know about the login or something i had already implemented that but i just want to access the value outside of the callback function and nothing else.According to the question But thanks for the effort

Comment: I showed you already how to access them from the same widget using StatefulWidget, and suggested Provider from other widgets. Anyway, I might've not understand your need.

Comment: Modified my answer, but I might be just shooting blanks.